# Dropdownlist using LINQ/MVC3/C# problem getting it to bind

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, bind

I am super new to MVC3 and C#, so excuse my noob questions. I have been struggling with this for almost a full day and hope someone can shed some light (I have scoured this site for clues, hints, answers as well).

I have a single table in my database which will hold all the data. It is for a profile editor which will store values that the user can populate their timekeeping entry form automatically upon select. I am on step one though, trying to populate the first dropdownlist with the profile name. I am using LINQ, MVC3/ Razer, and C#.

Here is my dbml:
Cant post image cause I am new

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/timem.png/

Here is my model:

```
namespace Timekeeping.Models
{

    public class Profile
    {
        public int Profile_ID { get; set; }
        public string profilename { get; set; }
        public string networkuserid { get; set; }
        public int projectnumber { get; set; }
        public int costcode { get; set; }
        public int paycode { get; set; }
        public int jobtype { get; set; }
        public int workorder { get; set; }
        public int activity { get; set; }
        public string taxarea { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Profile> profiles { get; set; }
    }



  public class ProfileViewModel
  {
      public int Profile_ID { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> profiles { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
namespace Timekeeping.Controllers
 public class TimeProfileController : Controller
    {


        private static String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["timekeepingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ProfileSelect()
        {

            profileConnectionDataContext dataContext = new profileConnectionDataContext(strConnString);
            var model = new ProfileViewModel();
            var rsProfile = from fbs in dataContext.TimeProfiles select fbs;

            ViewData["ProfileList"] = new SelectList(rsProfile, "Profile_ID", "profilename");
            return View(model);
        }


    }
```

And here are all the different html helpers I have tried for my View(none work):

```
 @Html.DropDownList("rsProfile", (SelectList)ViewData["ProfileList"]))

 @Html.DropDownListFor(
       x => x.Profile_ID,
       new SelectList(Model.profiles, "Values", "Text"),
       "-- Select--"
      )

  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Profile_ID, Model.profilename)
```

I know this is a mess to look at, but I am hoping someone can help so I can get on with the hard parts. Thanks in advance for any help I get from the community

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will work surely...

Inside Controller :

```
var lt = from result in db.Employees select new { result.EmpId, result.EmpName };
ViewData[ "courses" ] = new SelectList( lt, "EmpId", "EmpName" );
```

Inside View :

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("courses") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class TimeProfileController : Controller
{
    private static String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["timekeepingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ProfileSelect()
    {
        var dataContext = new profileConnectionDataContext(strConnString);
        var profiles = dataContext.TimeProfiles.ToArray().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Profile_ID,
            Text = x.profilename
        });
        var model = new ProfileViewModel
        {
            profiles = profiles
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model ProfileViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Profile_ID,
    new SelectList(Model.profiles, "Values", "Text"),
    "-- Select--"
)
```

Comment: There is a problem with:Value = fbs.Profile_ID,
            Text = fbs.profilename  Since fbs is not declared how can I use it? TY for your help man

Comment: @Alex, sorry, that's what happens when I type the code directly here without testing it. It should be `x` instead of `fbs` as that's how I named my variable.

Comment: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Line 51:                                     @Html.DropDownListFor(

Comment: @Alex, did you pass the model when you returned the view: `return View(model);` or you simply wrote `return View()`?

Comment: I did pass the model, and I have @model Timekeeping.Models.ProfileViewModel at the top of my partial view, maybe there is somthing wrong in my model

Comment: It seems, when I debug, that it is blowing up on the front end with the html helper. I do not think it is talking to the controller correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a model class just try this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("EmpId", new SelectList(Model, "EmpId", "EmpName")) %>
```

If you want to add click event for drop down list try this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("courses", ViewData["courses"] as SelectList, new { onchange = "redirect(this.value)" }) %>
```

In the above one `redirect(this.value)` is a JavaScript function